# Domain Model for Simple Yes/No

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Working from a `C#` and `EntityFramework` background. Jimmy Bogard makes the point of modelling your domain model correctly, such that an Email Address is not a simple `string` but should be of type `EmailAddress`.

Also known as Primitive Obsession.

I've come to this part of a piece of software where a Application form is to be filled out.

For the user a Yes/No question where they can answer Yes or No is a very easy thing, you can even create really go user experiences around yes/no.

So I have quickly thought of two ways to handle Yes/No.

A complex object:

```
public class YesNoAnswer
{
    public YesNoAnswer(string state) 
    {
        this.SetState(state);
    }

    public bool Yes { get; private set; }

    public void SetState(string state)
    {
        var uppedState = state.ToUpper();

        if (uppedState == "YES") 
        {
            this.Yes = true;
            return;
        }
        if (uppedState == "NO") 
        {
            this.Yes = false;
            return;
        }

        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(state), "Yes or No strings not found in argument");
    }
}
```

Or a simple extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool GetYesNoState(this string state) 
    {
        var uppedState = state.ToUpper();
    
        if (uppedState == "YES") 
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (uppedState == "NO") 
        {
            return false;
        }
    
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(state), "Yes or No strings not found in argument");
    }
}
```

Obviously the validation should be done earlier in the pipeline (or at least it is in our application).

Which is better? They both achieve the same thing, the first is much clearer, neater. The second is well, slightly obfuscated - not a great deal but takes more than a second to think about what it is doing.

#### Usage of both

```
var application = new ApplicationForm { IsOkayToWork = new YesNoAnswer(state) };
```

or

```
var application = new ApplicationForm { IsOkayToWork = state.GetYesNoState() };
```

Comment: Why is this *mutable*?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. `YesNoAnswer` has no property/field called `No` and `string` doesn't have either `Yes` or `No`.

Comment: it's more of a concept than actual working code, I only wrote that in the edit box. Why shouldn't the class be able to be changed? Are you saying just keep assigning a new value object to `IsOkayToWork` everytime you want assign a new value?

Comment: updated to compile now.

Comment: 1) `NO` should `return false` 2) I don't think you're allowed to edit code  like that.

Comment: 1) is does... 2) what do you mean "I don't think you're allowed to edit code like that"? what code, like how?

Comment: @CallumLinington Not sure, but my guess is he means don't edit code after you get an answer, because it potentially invalidates that answer. However since it was fixing a bug and I don't think it was referenced in the answer, IMO it's fine in this case.

Comment: The email example is a good one because there's likely to be lots of validation logic encapsulated in the class. What do you hope to encapsulate or achieve with this class that can't be accomplished with a simple Boolean?

Comment: Well that was my thought! All this does is mirror the front end and act like a bool in business logic. It prevents the UI from having view logic to transform bool into yes or no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of creating a **Value Object** instead of using primitives is to have a highly descriptive domain. Using the second option (the extension method) misses the point. You definitely want to be using the first.

e.g.

```
public class QuestionAnswer
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    public YesNoAnswer YesNoValue { get; set; }
}
```

Is more descriptive and specific than:

```
public class QuestionAnswer
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    public bool YesNoValue { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class QuestionAnswer
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    public string YesNoValue { get; set; }
}
```

One thing I would add is that you probably want a conversion to bool:

```
public class YesNoAnswer
{
    // omitted

    public static implicit operator bool(YesNoAnswer answer)
    {
        return (answer?.Yes).GetValueOrDefault();
    }

}
```

Then you can use it naturally in code:

```
var someAnswer = new QuestionAnswer { QuestionId = 1, YesNoValue = new YesNoAnswer("YES") }:

if (someAnswer.YesNoValue)
{

}
```

You should also override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` as Value Objects should have value equality not reference equality.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was leaning towards. What property type did you have holding the yes/no value in `YesNoAnswer`? Was it a string of the response? I like the bool conversion, that is a nice touch

Comment: @CallumLinington You can have whichever you like. You don't even really need a property if you only consider it as a bool in consuming code.